# Auto complete type in text field from a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know if it is simple or no. What I want to solve is,
One drop down "select" form field is there, another "input type="text" " field is below. Some options are there in "select dropdown". When I type in Below "input type="text" " field, There should be some suggestions from the above "select" dropdown field (like Auto Complete). Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal `<select>` tag with [Select2](http://select2.github.io):

```js
$(function () {
  $("select").select2({
    width: 250
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" />
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="item-1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="item-2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="item-3">Item 3</option>
  <option value="item-4">Item 4</option>
  <option value="item-5">Item 5</option>
  <option value="entry-1">Entry 1</option>
  <option value="entry-2">Entry 2</option>
  <option value="entry-3">Entry 3</option>
  <option value="entry-4">Entry 4</option>
  <option value="entry-5">Entry 5</option>
  <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="option-4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="option-5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```